# create scrollview programmatically in swift without outlet

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have tried enough but i don't understand what is wrong with code, it was working fine when I created an outlet, but then I found out that i don't need an outlet, so want to create it just programmatically.

```
var BestPractices = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 94, 768, 924))
BestPractices.hidden = true
```

I cannot access the properties of "BestPractices" in viewController , while same code works fine in playground

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223768/how-to-construct-a-scrollview-using-swift) question. 
.

```
class ScrollingViewController : UIViewController {
// Create a scrollView property that we'll set as our view in -loadView
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

override func loadView() {
    // calling self.view later on will return a UIView!, but we can simply call 
    // self.scrollView to adjust properties of the scroll view:
    self.view = self.scrollView

    // setup the scroll view
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:1234, height: 5678)
    // etc...
}

func example() {
    let sampleSubView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(sampleSubView) // adds to the scroll view

    // cannot do this:
    // self.view.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
    // so instead we do this:
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
}
```

Comment: Very good answer! But I have one problem It returns me black background and i can't change it .

Answer (score 0):

add this line to identify scroll bar at last of loadview().

```
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```